# Linq to Dataset C#

Tags: c#, linq, ms-access-2013

So I have a table called `groupe_stg`  it contains 2 foreign keys `code_demande` , `code_stagiaire`  and at the same time they are primary keys.
In my app I have the `code_stagiaire`  and from it I want to retrieve it's `code_demande`. Basically what am trying to say is:

```
select code_demande 
from group_stg 
where code_stagiaire = "parameter"`
```

I would've create a stored procedure it would be easier , but unfortunately I was forced to work with an access database

This is my solution for the LINQ code,

```
String code_linq()
{
    var query = from g in Program.mds.group_stg
                where g.cin_stagiaire == txt_cin.Text
                select new
                {
                    code = g.code_demande
                };

    return query.ToString();
}
```

As you can see it is some sort a scalar function
but this code is giving me this exception:

> system.data.enumerablerowcollection'1 [<>
>   f_anonymousType0'1[System.String]]

Comment: _"System.data.enumerablerowcollection"_ is not an exception.

Comment: And there is no scalar function anywhere in your code, it's a query that returns an enumerable, ie objects. By calling `ToString` on the enumerable, you got back the variable's type - the default behaviour of `ToString`

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting multiple `code_demande` in an anonymous type but you want a single string.

If you just want the first `code_demande` which has `cin_stagiaire == txt_cin.Text`:

```
var demands = from g in Program.mds.group_stg
              where g.cin_stagiaire == txt_cin.Text
              select g.code_demande;
return demands.FirstOrdefault();  // null if no match
```

Comment: the method ( FirstOrdefault() ) is underlined in RED and it says this message (' system.data.EnumerableRow..... ' does not contain definition for 'FirstOrdefault' and no extension method accepting a first argument. do you have any idea ? sir